# Ghost Accounts in banking

Tags: app, accounts, banking

last couple of days I tried to figure out combination of requirements from Online sales department for our e-banking app.

The main theme are "ghost accounts", I would rather call them "fake products". As a client you can have plenty of different financial products. Usually it´s a bank account (or several), but you can have some credit products, like a loans.

This products you already have are places clearly on the welcome screen. Now sales would like to mix them with the ghost accounts. The welcome screen consists of tiles - 1 for every product. Tile for the loan you already have has specific info like:

- name and ID of the product and the name of the owner
- amount of money on this credit card - for example
- amount of blocked money
- how much a when is your next repayment
- and several shorcuts to the basic operation for this product

They plan this ghost accounts tiles to look like your real product, except the only shortcut action would be "Purchase".

I´m not thrilled.... As a client I would be shocked at least for the first moment because it would look like I have some unknown new debts....

Don´t you someone have some study or experience with such a thing? I don´t like the risk of confusing our clients. My preference would be no mix, but two separate categories like "this you have" a "you can purchase this as well".

Comment: I'm not really clear what the problem you need solving here is. Do you want some advice for how to display these promotional products? What specifically would you be looking for in an answer?
Also, do you have you got any mockups / wireframes of how it currently works?

Answer (score 3):

This is an information architecture problem, try fixing it by adding an additional level to your data hierarchy.

You can solve some of the user confusion in seeing products they own mixed in with products your company wants them to purchase by splitting them out into two sections of the page with headers.

Rather than:

Product I Own, Product I Own, Some Other Product [Purchase], Product I Own

Show:

My Products

Product I Own, Product I Own, Product I Own

Deals For You

Some Other Product [Purchase], Some Other Product [Purchase], Some Other Product [Purchase]